# Runnable JAR file error: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java-7, runnable, eclipse-indigo

I made an application in Java (version 7) with Eclipse (Indigo) when I exported my application interface on a Runnable JAR file on my computer and tried it worked fine, then I tried on another computer and I get this problem

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: cliente/Princ
ipal : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
```

I saw other post that this can be because the other computer have an older version of Java than mine, can somebody confirm this please?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the error when you try to run Java bytecode with an older version that the version you build it with.

You will find [more information in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0).

Comment: Thanks!, I already checked in a computer with the same version as mine and it works.